# How to check last 3 chars of a string are alphabets or not using awk?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I want to check if the last 3 letters in column 1 are alphabets and print those rows. What am I doing wrong?

My code :-

```
awk -F '|' ' {print str=substr( $1 , length($1) - 2) } END{if ($str ~ /^[A-Za-z]/ ) print}' file
```

cat file

```
12300USD|0392
abc56eur|97834
238aed|23911
aabccde|38731
73716yen|19287
.*/|982376
0NRT0|928731
```

expected output :

```
12300USD|0392
abc56eur|97834
238aed|23911
aabccxx|38731
73716yen|19287
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /[[:alpha:]]{3}$/' file
12300USD|0392
abc56eur|97834
238aed|23911
aabccde|38731
73716yen|19287
```

Regarding what's wrong with your script:

- You're doing the test for alphabetic characters in the END section for the final line read instead of once per input line.
- You're trying to use shell variable syntax `$str` instead of awk `str`.
- You're testing for literal character ranges in the bracket expression instead of using a character class so YMMV on which characters that includes depending on your locale.
- You're testing for a string that starts with a letter instead of a string that ends with 3 letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -P '^[^|]*[A-Za-z]{3}[|]' in_file > out_file
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following option:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.

The regex means this:
`^` : Start of the string.
`[^|]*` : Any non-pipe character, repeated 0 or more times.
`[A-Za-z]{3}` : 3 letters.
`[|]` : Literal pipe.

Comment: No need for the gnu-only non-portable `-P`, that's just an ERE so you could use `-E` in any POSIX grep.

Comment: @EdMorton: Since we are on the subject, allow me to thank you for your answers and comments - I always learn a lot from them!

Comment: @EdMorton Too bad #metoo is taken for something else.

Comment: Timur & @JamesBrown you're welcome. I get more out of this forum than I put into it and learn something new almost every day so I'm always happy to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^[^|]*[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]|/p' file
grep '^[^|]*[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk    '!+FS<NF' FS='^[^|]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][|]'

{m,g}awk '$!_!~"[|]"'       FS='[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][|]'
{m,g}awk '($!_~"[|]")<NF'   FS='[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][|]' # to play it safe

12300USD|0392
abc56eur|97834
238aed|23911
aabccde|38731
73716yen|19287
```